# How to convert a Array (JSON Array) to Map?

Tags: javascript, java, json, selenium, collections

My script returns me a Array (JSON Array) as follows :

```
[{redirectCount=0, encodedBodySize=60962, unloadEventEnd=0, responseEnd=1601.699999999255, domainLookupEnd=995.7999999896856, unloadEventStart=0, domContentLoadedEventStart=1970.3999999910593, type=navigate, decodedBodySize=215675, duration=3103.799999997136, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=1357.1999999985565, toJSON={}, requestStart=1359.599999996135, startTime=0, fetchStart=1598.6999999877298, serverTiming=[], domContentLoadedEventEnd=1981.999999989057, entryType=navigation, workerStart=0, responseStart=1499.7000000003027, domInteractive=1970.2999999863096, domComplete=3093.799999987823, domainLookupStart=995.7999999896856, redirectEnd=0, transferSize=65141, connectStart=995.7999999896856, loadEventStart=3094.4999999919673, secureConnectionStart=1041.6999999870313, name=http://www.google.com/, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=navigation, loadEventEnd=3103.799999997136}, {encodedBodySize=5087, entryType=resource, responseEnd=1782.099999996717, workerStart=0, responseStart=1732.5999999884516, domainLookupEnd=1646.7999999877065, domainLookupStart=1646.7999999877065, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=5087, duration=135.30000000901055, transferSize=5262, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=1646.7999999877065, toJSON={}, connectStart=1646.7999999877065, requestStart=1648.1999999959953, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png, startTime=1646.7999999877065, fetchStart=1646.7999999877065, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=5969, entryType=resource, responseEnd=1919.0999999991618, workerStart=0, responseStart=1777.9999999911524, domainLookupEnd=1647.0999999874039, domainLookupStart=1647.0999999874039, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=5969, duration=272.00000001175795, transferSize=6039, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=1647.0999999874039, toJSON={}, connectStart=1647.0999999874039, requestStart=1648.6999999906402, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png, startTime=1647.0999999874039, fetchStart=1647.0999999874039, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=1985.7999999949243, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=320.5000000016298, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png, startTime=1665.2999999932945, fetchStart=1665.2999999932945, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=css}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2168.599999989965, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=387.09999999264255, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.com/gen_204?dml=1, startTime=1781.4999999973224, fetchStart=1781.4999999973224, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {duration=0, entryType=paint, toJSON={}, name=first-paint, startTime=1781.5999999875203}, {duration=0, entryType=paint, toJSON={}, name=first-contentful-paint, startTime=1781.5999999875203}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2054.49999999837, workerStart=0, responseStart=2053.599999999278, domainLookupEnd=1969.699999986915, domainLookupStart=1969.699999986915, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=84.80000001145527, transferSize=56, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=1969.699999986915, toJSON={}, connectStart=1969.699999986915, requestStart=1970.7999999955064, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?s=webaft&atyp=csi&ei=JwmtWtvfK4jrvgSd2rSoDA&rt=wsrt.1622,aft.346,prt.346, startTime=1969.699999986915, fetchStart=1969.699999986915, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=beacon}, {encodedBodySize=150145, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2339.9999999965075, workerStart=0, responseStart=2215.3999999864027, domainLookupEnd=1985.000000000582, domainLookupStart=1985.000000000582, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=432554, duration=354.99999999592546, transferSize=150402, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=1985.000000000582, toJSON={}, connectStart=1985.000000000582, requestStart=2167.799999995623, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.ruBw46222DE.O/m=sx,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/am=wCJ0xz8A-f_BgCLRCkZYgGjBMDQ/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oHcVyvrSVGpTIcAIyAYtf5uuQMgeg, startTime=1985.000000000582, fetchStart=1985.000000000582, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2543.20000000007, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=358.0000000074506, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.og2.en_US.WC6JeWv9ETU.O/rt=j/m=def/exm=in,fot/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTu6Da9cmMJFbNF2zgt8mvkJOB8gGQ, startTime=2185.1999999926193, fetchStart=2185.1999999926193, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=33183, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2536.19999998773, workerStart=0, responseStart=2515.89999999851, domainLookupEnd=2451.3000000006286, domainLookupStart=2451.3000000006286, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=100255, duration=84.89999998710118, transferSize=33295, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=2451.3000000006286, toJSON={}, connectStart=2451.3000000006286, requestStart=2461.4000000001397, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.ruBw46222DE.O/m=aa,abd,async,dvl,foot,fpe,ipv6,lu,m,mu,sf,sonic,spch,d3l,udlg/am=wCJ0xz8A-f_BgCLRCkZYgGjBMDQ/exm=sx,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/rt=j/d=1/ed=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oHcVyvrSVGpTIcAIyAYtf5uuQMgeg?xjs=s1, startTime=2451.3000000006286, fetchStart=2451.3000000006286, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=2666.6999999870313, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=165.79999998793937, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png, startTime=2500.899999999092, fetchStart=2500.899999999092, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=3038.4999999951106, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=345.1000000059139, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.KGfejEJNA7c.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AAE/rs=AHpOoo8sfkynV0sdMp9PqJxnrfktogrWdA/cb=gapi.loaded_0, startTime=2693.3999999891967, fetchStart=2693.3999999891967, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=3129.799999995157, workerStart=0, responseStart=3129.3000000005122, domainLookupEnd=3044.899999993504, domainLookupStart=3044.899999993504, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=84.9000000016531, transferSize=54, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=3044.899999993504, toJSON={}, connectStart=3044.899999993504, requestStart=3046.8999999866355, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=&cad=udla=1&ei=JwmtWtvfK4jrvgSd2rSoDA&di=3325&lt=-66418&ln=-307466&zx=1521289508660, startTime=3044.899999993504, fetchStart=3044.899999993504, serverTiming=[], nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=beacon}]
```

I need to print the *Key* / *Pair* values just like I print from a *Map* as follows :

```
Map<String, ?> map = cap.asMap();
for ( Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " value is " + entry.getValue());
}
```

I have tried to follow the following links but still no success:

- [How can i print json objects and array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733020/how-can-i-print-json-objects-and-array-values)
- [How to Print JSON Array returned from controller class to jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501208/how-to-print-json-array-returned-from-controller-class-to-jsp-page)
- [JSON - Iterate through JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697147/json-iterate-through-jsonarray)

Is it possible the JSON format I am recieving is different from the regular JSON formats?

My current code is based on *Selenium* which uses a *Javascript* to read the performance statistics as follows :

```
String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
System.out.println(netData);
```

*JavaDocs* of [`executeScript()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) mentions the following :

If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains a return statement), then the following steps will be taken:

- For an HTML element, this method returns a WebElement
- For a decimal, a Double is returned
- For a non-decimal number, a Long is returned
- For a boolean, a Boolean is returned
- For all other cases, a String is returned.
- For an array, return a List with each object following the rules above. We support nested lists.
- For a map, return a Map with values following the rules above.
- Unless the value is null or there is no return value, in which null is returned

Comment: The json format returned by script is not valid. Key value separator is supposed to be `:` instead of `=`

Comment: Can you please have a relook at the Array within the question please. It contains something as `toJSON={}`. I am still clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for not so complicated jsons, you can try doing it manually...

first remove { and [

```
jsontext = jsontext.replaceAll ("[\\[\\]{}]", "");
```

then split the json array using the , separator

```
String[] items = jsontext.split(",");
```

then for each item, split using the = separator, and then populate into your array

```
Map<String, String> array;

for (String s: items){

    String[] item = s.split("=");
    if(item.length == 2){
        array.put(item[0].trim(), item[1].trim());
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error with: "+ s);
    }
}
```

if you want ? as your map array, then you have to do your own conversion from String to Int, etc...

for more complicated jsons (arrays within arrays, etc), you may have to resolve and save the inner arrays first, then resolve the outer arrays.