# How can I filter entries of network calls by name in Python using selenium chrome driver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm struggling to filter network calls by name in python. I could read through the whole object separately from the API but I can see it's possible in JavaScript. Can someone explain how to do this in Python?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')


performance_data = browser.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries("widget", "mark");')
file = open('Hero.txt', 'w+')


for performance_datas in performance_data:
    file.write(str(performance_data))
```

This will write all the network calls as an object into Hero.txt. I want to be able to filter this with all the network calls where the name has widget in the request url. Can I do this using the API or does this need to be done after all the network calls have loaded in Hero.txt?

Comment: Does this address your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336211/how-to-convert-a-array-json-array-to-map

Comment: @DebanjanB that converts json to a map, then you can get the key values. I want to get the name before it's even written to a json so it returns just the name in the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for single_data in performance_data:
  if "widget" in single_data["name"]:
    file.write(str(single_data))
```

Comment: I tried that but get this 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Sorry I misinterpret your code. I fix it now, please try

Comment: Good answer (+1). But @Sam this answer even won't _get the name before it's written to a json_

Comment: @DebanjanB my bad maybe it was confusing the way I wrote it. It only writes that name of associated request to the json. So in a way it does get it before I write it to the file.